# Accordion angularjs using bootstrap collapse

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

On my AngularJS app, I have a component `<address>` that use `collapse` from bootstrap. It was working perfectly until I tried to use a dynamic **ID** for the content to hide.

It was required since I'm using two `<address>` in the parent component, to avoid **ID** conflicts.

**HTML sample :**

```
<div ng-class="$ctrl.getAddressAccordionClass()">
    <h3 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#$ctrl.addressId" ng-click="$ctrl.toggleAccordion();">
        <span>{{$ctrl.boxTitle}}</span>
    </h3>
    <div ng-attr-id="$ctrl.addressId" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
       <p>some content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I saw that I can use `ng-attr-id` to set a dynamic id. But how can I inject my id into `data-target` property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked too early the answer was simple, simply add double curly braces **{{ }}** :

```
<div ng-class="$ctrl.getAddressAccordionClass()">
    <h3 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{$ctrl.addressId}}" ng- click="$ctrl.toggleAccordion();">
    <span>{{$ctrl.boxTitle}}</span>
</h3>
<div ng-attr-id="{{$ctrl.addressId}}" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
   <p>some content</p>
</div>
```